# Arthur Milgram photo

Tags: soft-question, mathematicians

someone has photo of Arthur Milgram?  (the guy from Lax-Milgram Theorem)

I'm curious, why I can't find one picture of Arthur Milgram on google?

Anyone has one? or where can I find one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [small, low-quality photo on the dedication page](https://encrypted.google.com/books?id=UEVY9MmIfrYC&lpg=PR7&pg=PR7#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Partial differential equations, by Lipman Bers, Fritz John and Martin Schechter, New York: Interscience, 1964.

If one has a good use for a clearer photo, one might hope to contact his [mathematical descendants](http://www.genealogy.ams.org/id.php?id=360) or his son, R. James Milgram, a professor emeritus who has been active at his Stanford Math email address during the past year.